# Flexbox (display: flex) not working on iOS 13

Tags: css, flexbox, mobile-safari, ios13

The problem happens on **Safari** browser with **iOS 13**.

The page is a static html using bootstrap 4 and AngularJS.

Here is the link to the code http://jsfiddle.net/dermingo/q1mygfnh/15/

and here a testeable link http://jsfiddle.net/dermingo/q1mygfnh/15/show (just in case)

The behavior is the following:

[image: Bug on iOS 13 caused by display flex (I believe)]

- You click on the *picture with the #1* (or 2) and land on a slider
- Click on *Go back*
- And you'll notice that some styles have crashed

If you inspect it, you can see the problem coming from the class `.row`:

```
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

By adding a space to the `display: flex;` and then remove it, the class comes back to life:

[image]

Why is behaving this way and how can I fix it?